# Linked List implementation of a Graph

Tags: c++, graph-theory

I'm pretty new to C++.

I'm trying to create an adjacency list implementation of a graph with linked nodes, visually it'll look something like this:

```
[Headnode Vertex | Next Node] -> [Adjacent Node Vertex | Next] -> etc
[0 | ]-> [1 | ]-> [2 | ]-> [NULL node]
[1 | ]-> [0 | ]-> [2 | ]-> [NULL node]
[2 | ]-> [0 | ]-> [1 | ]-> [NULL node]
```

A graph of 3 nodes, with vertices numbered 0-2, right?

So Here is the code I am implementing:

```
struct node {
    int vertex;
    node *next;
};

node *headnodes;
bool *Visited;
bool cycles = false;// determine if a graph has cycles.

class Graph {

    private: 
        int n; // number of vertices
        int e; // number of edges
        //node *headnodes;

    public:  
        Graph(int nodes) // construtor
        {
            n = nodes;
            headnodes = new node[n]; // headnodes is an array of nodes.
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            {
                headnodes[i].vertex = i;
                headnodes[i].next = 0; //points null
            }
        }

        //This function is based off lecture notes (Lecture 13)
        //node graph
        int Graph::create()
        {
            //iterate through the head nodes
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                cout << "Initializing " << i << "-th node.\n";
                if (i == 0){
                    //headnode 0 points to its adjacent nodes 1, and 2
                    headnodes[n].next = new node; //initialize new node
                    node link = headnodes[n]; //assign to new variable
                    link.vertex = 1;
                    link.next->vertex = 2;
                    link.next->next = 0;
//This works
                    cout << "vertex of first node: " << headnodes[n].next->vertex; 
                } else if (i == 1){
                    headnodes[n].next = new node; //initialize new node
                    node link = headnodes[n];
                    link.vertex = 0; //the first node
                    link.next->vertex = 3; //the second node
                    //the 3rd node
                    /*link.next = new node;
                    node *link2 = link.next;
                    link.next->next->vertex = 4;
                    link.next->next->next = 0;*/
                } else if (i == 2){
                    headnodes[n].next = new node; //initialize new node
                    node link = headnodes[n];
                    link.vertex = 0;
                    link.next->vertex = 3;
                    link.next->next = 0;
                }
            }
//This doesn't?
            cout << "Checking vertex";
            cout << "First node's link vert: " << headnodes[0].next->vertex; //ERROR, Access Violation!
            return 0;
        }
};
```

I figured since the headnodes variable is global it would be fine but it's causing a RunTime error (Access Violation), apparently it's pointing to a null node (but it's global so wth)? I don't get what's wrong.

Can someone point me in the right direction. I feel I'm close.

Comment: Why does it being global stop it from being null?

Comment: because it gets initialized inside the Graph's Create function...right?
From what I understand, the Graph's constructor creates a pointer to an array of headnodes, and initializes each head node to point to a null node.
The Create function populates those headnodes. So it's no longer pointing to null nodes (That's I'm trying to attempt anyway)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is pretty straight forward. In your `create` function you try to iterate over the adjacency lists however you continually index the `n-th` `headnode` which you probably know is outside the bounds of the array.

You pass in 3 as `nodes` and assign it to `n` and in your loop continue to index it as `headnodes[n]`. You can verify this by adding `cout << n << endl;` before each access of `headnodes`; you'll see `3` each time.

You likely want to index them according to `i` as that would be the iteration index.

Comment: That was the issue. Oh also, I made it global so my main function can have access to it. I couldn't get my program to work with the headnode variable as a private member of Graph

Comment: OK, feel free to accept it as the answer then. I imagined that although I can't recommend doing it. The better option is to encapsulate those aspects especially in this case. As you wouldn't be so crazy to corrupt your graph on purpose, it's generally not sufficient to assume the same from other users, graders, or professors. You should be able to provide a graph such that the user should not need or want to know about the notion of `headnodes`. My comment though was really to point out that visibility in no way guarantees an object isn't null. @mastrgamr

Comment: I understand that, I'm wrestling with null checking where nodes point to now. Good Luck to me! *face-palm*